# first activity's onPause not called when start two activity continuously and the second activity with translucent theme

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

Just as the title described, when I start two activity continuously， and the second activity has a theme that `windowIsTranslucent` is true。
I found that the first activity's `onPause` was not called, it means that all of this activities were under resumed status.
this problem just happen on android pie(API 28) or higher

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class));
startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
```

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppThemeA" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

```
    <application
        android:name="com.taou.maimai.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeA">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.taou.maimai.Activity1" />
        <activity android:name="com.taou.maimai.Activity2"
            />
    </application>
```

Comment: Are you setting the theme from the AndroidManifest ?

Comment: yes,I set the theme in AndroidManifest

Comment: post your theme

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the theme in `onCreate` like this:

```
 public void onCreate(..){
    super.onCreate();
    setTheme(R.style.transcluent_theme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_2);

  }
```